# C# text file deduping based on split

Tags: c#

what i want to do is de-dupe a text file (against itself) based on the split.  Once the de-dupe has been complete write out to a new file and keep the first result.  So a basic example is.  I guess the question is how do you de dupe a text file in C# based on a string split.

File 1:
Apple|Turnip3234
Apple|Tunip22
Fox|dsa34
Turtle|3423
Hamster|d34
Fox|sdw2

Result:
Apple|Turnip3234
Fox|dsa34
Turtle|3423
Hamster|d34

Comment: You need to make explicit what constitutes a "dupe" and how to select which one to keep.

Comment: C# would work, but for something so simple I might recommend a tool like Ruby, Python, or Perl.  You won't notice an appreciable time difference unless the files in question are huge!  That being said, you're going to use a Dictionary data structure in any language to achieve this (check if the key is present, if it is add it, otherwise skip adding it to the dictionary), then for each line in the original lookup the other side of the split and print them.

Comment: @Cpfohl: If he know C# or C or something similar (at least some syntax) and don't know Ruby at all, he probably do it sooner in C#.

Comment: @Cpfohl: what if the rest of the application is written in C#? Is it that good to use Ruby, Python, or Perl for this? Maybe you could justify IronRuby or IronPython (is there IronPerl? I hope not), but spinning off the native interpreter sounds totally overkill to me.

Comment: @Martinho the rest of the application doesn't exist.  Read the question carefully, it says, "input file" "output file".  I worked in NLP for quite some time and usually tools like these were an intermediate step between other programs.  I was basing this off experience. @Al, you're probably right, but it's worth getting to know a scripting language because eventually it will *always* be faster to use one.

Comment: The rest of the app does exist.  But yes, i would prefer not to cross languages

Comment: That's fine, you've got some great answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string inputFile; // = ...
string outputFile; // = ...
HashSet<string> keys = new HashSet<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFile))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        string candidate = line.Split('|')[0];
        if (keys.Add(candidate))
            writer.WriteLine(line);

        line = reader.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashSet<string>`. Store there left part of line (everything preceding `|`).

On each line call `hashset.Contains(leftpart)` to test if that line is a "dupe".

Comment: Right. No need to store the lines, the first 'unique' one can be written directly.

Comment: Yes of course, you can write directly, just need to keep the hashset.

Comment: @Al: I'm pretty sure Henk was agreeing with you.

Comment: @Adam: Yes I was. It was the 1st answer w/o Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Dictionary<string,string>` where key is your first word and value is the second one. Then you can just go through all your lines, split them and check if first word occurs in `Keys`, and add this pair if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This will always use the first value encountered (and it's untested, but the concepts are correct).

```
Dictionary<String, String> dupeMap = new Dictionary<String, String>();
foreach (string line in File.Readlines("foo.txt")) {
    key = line.Split("|")[0];
    if (!dupeMap.ContainsKey(key)) {
        dupeMap.Add(key, line);
    }
}
```

Then you can write them all back by iterating over the `Dictionary`, though this is **not** stable because you can't be certain to get the lines back in order.

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("foo.txt")) {
    foreach (string key in dupeMap.Keys()) {
        tw.WriteLine(dupeMap[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to only add values you haven't met yet.

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.txt");

    Dictionary<string, string> allUniques = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach(string s in allLines)
    {
        var chunks = s.Split('|');
        if (!allUniques.ContainsKey(chunks[0]))
        {
            allUniques.Add(chunks[0], s);
        }       
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\test2.txt", allUniques.Values.ToArray());
```